# Custom plugin dynamics 365 v9 not showing in plugin registration

Tags: dynamics-365, xrmtoolbox

I got a problem with view in plugin registration,

First i was uninstalled project solution from my dynamics 365 v9, and then all of my custom plugin disappear from view in plugin registration, now just show 3 plugin, activityfeeds.filtering.plugin, activityFeeds.Plugins, and Microsoft.Dynamics.ProjectService.Plugins. But my custom plugin not disappeared from my solution in dynamics 365.

Problem is when i want to update my custom plugin, i can not update because they not showing and cannot be selected.

Please help

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The PluginRegistrationTool that comes in the XrmToolBox is not supported by MS, so always try the one found in the SDK.  The easiest method I know of downloading the SDK is to go to http://xrm.tools/SDK and download the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider that the solution you removed could have been managed. In that case it will remove all the components (the behavior is what you observed). In that case you will need to re-register everything. 
What Daryl says it's correct, but in case of incompatibility usually the external components are failing to connect.